# color animation to the fragment not whole fragment animation

Tags: android-fragments, fragment, android-animation

I have three fragments one on the left,top and right, now I want only color to come as animation on the left fragment not whole left fragment to animate. so I commented the third line of code stop the whole left fragment animation

```
LogoFragment logo = new LogoFragment();
logo.setArguments(bundle1);
//fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_left_right, R.anim.fade_right_left);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.logoContainer,logo);
```

but the color is setting like normal `setTextColor` although I need the color to be set as animation.